Why are the outputs same for both of these loops? Can anyone explain me with the dry run step-by-step? please?
Why are the outputs same for both of these loops? Can anyone explain me with the dry run step-by-step? please? I have been struggling with this for hours.
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    

    // Post-increment (i++)
    for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Pre-increment (++i)
    for(int i=1; i<=5; ++i){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

I expected:
1 2 3 4 5  
2 3 4 5 


Either ++i or i++ happens always at the end of each iteration (the pre increment does not happen before each ietration).  Pre vs. post increment matters within a single statement, not in the for loop control flow context. You can use single-step with a debugger to observe it.

Post-increment and pre-increment within a 'for' loop produce same output and Difference between pre-increment and post-increment in a loop?

It has to do with how for loop syntax works in C++.  Your first loop is similar to this:
int i=1;
while(i<=5){
    std::cout << i << " ";
    i++;
}

Now you can see that i++ vs ++i makes no difference, because the return value of the increment operator is not used.  The only work done is actually incrementing i and it makes no difference whether you do it using i++ or ++i.

I’d even bet the machine code is identical in both cases for most (if not all reasonably modern) compilers since they realise (even with optimization turned off, IIRC) that making a copy is just waste.

The third expression in a for loop is executed always at the end of each iteration.
The only difference between your two expressions is that i++ takes a copy of i, adds to it and stores it in i, and ++i increases i directly.
But no matter what, they are only executed at the end of the iteration, so the results are the same (except some very minor performance differences)
